# responsive background image header in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to put a header before the navigation bar in my bootstrap page. The header will be an image that I want resizes correctly for mobiles, desktops etc. How do I go I about this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size`

```
div.someclass {
  background-size: cover;
}
```